# Emacs colourize string for mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use ERC for IRC, and would like to colourize some of my messages.

Basically, I want to colourize my input based on a specified major mode.

As an example, if I write `/hs 1 + 2`, it would colourize, and send the message as if it were in a buffer with Haskell Mode.

I already know how to write slash commands for ERC, I just don't know how to colourize the string based on a mode.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this -- and I think it is used in other spots, like gnus -- is to make a temporary buffer, set the mode of the buffer, insert the text, and then force it to font-lock.  Then, extract the buffer text with properties, and copy that wherever you like.

Offhand I don't know how to force font-locking to happen.  You may need to dig into the jit-lock code a bit.